# ID fields in SQL tables: rule or law?

Tags: sql

Just a quick database design question: Do you ALWAYS use an ID field in EVERY table, or just most of them?  Clearly most of your tables will benefit, but are there ever tables that you might not want to use an ID field?

For example, I want to add the ability to add tags to objects in another table (foo).  So I've got a table FooTag with a varchar field to hold the tag, and a fooID field to refer to the row in foo.  Do I really need to create a clustered index around an essentially arbitrary ID field?  Wouldn't it be more efficient to use fooID and my text field as the clustered index, since I will almost always be searching by fooID anyway?  Plus using my text in the clustered index would keep the data sorted, making sorting easier when I have to query my data.  The downside is that inserts would take longer, but wouldn't that be offset by the gains during selection, which would happen far more often?

What are your thoughts on ID fields?  Bendable rule, or unbreakable law?

edit: I am aware that the example provided is not normalized.  If tagging is to be a major part of the project, with multiple tables being tagged, and other 'extras', a two-table solution would be a clear answer.  However in this simplest case, would normalization be worthwhile?  It would save some space, but require an extra join when running queries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in much of programming: **rule, not law**.

Proof by exception: Some two-column tables exist only to form relationships between other more meaningful tables.

Answer (score 3):

If you are making tables that bridge between two or more other tables and the only fields you need are the dual PK/FK's, then I don't know why you would need ID column in there as well.

ID columns generally can be very helpful, but that doesn't mean you should go peppering them in at every occasion.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's a general,  rather than absolute, rule and there are plenty of exceptions (tables with composite keys for example).

There are some occasional but useful occasions where you might want to create an artificial ID in a table that already has a (usually composite) unique identifier. For example, in one system I've created a table to store part numbers; although the part numbers are unique, they may actually change - we add an arbitrary integer PartID. Not so common, but it's a typical real-world example.

Answer (score 1):

In general what you really want is to be able if at all possible to have some kind of way to uniquely identify a record. It could be an id field or it could be a unique index (which does not have to be on just one field). Anytime I thought I could get away without creating a way to uniquely identify a record, I have been proven wrong. All tables do not have a natural key though and if they do not, you really need to have an id file of some kind. If you have a natural key, you could use that instead, but I find that even then I need an id field in most cases to prevent having to do too much updating when the natural key changes (it always seems to change). Plus having worked with literally hundreds of databases concerning many many differnt topics, I can tell you that a true natural key is rare.  As others have nmentioned there is no need  for an id field in a table that is simply there to join two tables that havea many to many relationship, but even this should have a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve records from that table with unique id then yes.  If you will retrieve them by some other composite key made up of foreign keys then no.  The last thing you need is fields, data, and indexes that you do not use.

Answer (score 0):

A clustered index does not need to be on primary key or a surrogate (identity column) either.

Your design, however, is not normalized.  Typically for tagging, I use two tables, a table of tags (with a surrogate key) and a table of links from the tags to the subject table(s) using the surrogate key in the tag table and theprimary key in the subject table.  This allows your tags to apply to different entities (photos, articles, employees, locations, products, whatever).  It allows you to enforce foreign key relationships to multiple tables, and also allows you to invent tag hierarchies and other things about the tag table.

As far as the indexes on this design, it will be dictated by the usage patterns.

Answer (score 0):

In general developers love having an ID field on all tables except for 'linking' tables because it makes development much easier, and I am no exception to this. DBA's on the other hand see no problem with making natural primary keys made up of 3 or 4 columns. It can be a butting of heads to try and get a good database design.