# MySQL unique id or combined id

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have the following structure for my project and developer program:

```
developer table
id
developer name
etc...

project table
id
project name
etc...

developer _project table
???
```

Because a developer can be in multiple projects and a projects can have multiple developer I have to create a new table but from what I read is they don't tell what id should I use.

If I use an id auto increment + user_id + project_id will I have duplicate since the id is the primary key?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a unique combined key:

```
CREATE TABLE `developer_project` (
 developer_id INT(10) UNSIGNED /* etc... */,
 project_id INT(10) UNSIGNED /* etc... */,
 PRIMARY KEY dev_project (developer_id, project_id)
);
```

If you create an `ID` you will probably never use it since you will query the developer_id and/or project_id in your `LEFT JOIN`

*NOTE: make sure the column definitions are the same as the `developer` and the `project` tables.*

Comment: why they need to be the same definition?

Comment: let's say you have `INT UNSIGNED` (max value 4294967295 because is unsigned) from the developer table and `tinyint` (max value is 127 because its signed - the `unsigned` word is not defined) in the intersection table. Because the max number in the intersection table is reached, it wont insert more than this number, it will stop at 127 (you will get: `Out of range value for column 'developer_id' at row 1`). read more: http://help.scibit.com/mascon/masconMySQL_Field_Types.html

Answer (score 5):

for many-to-many relationship, you could simply use composite primary key of two fields.

Example (assuming both project_id and developer_id is integer):

```
CREATE TABLE `developer_project` (
  `developer_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `project_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (  `developer_id` ,  `project_id` )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A combined table (in MySQL workbench automatically called "developer_has_project") should use a combined primary key (developer,project). If you add a third column to this key (ID) it no longer has to be unique:

```
(id,developer,project)
(1,1,1)
(2,1,1)
(3,1,1)
```

Using only the developer and project, it will work:

```
(developer,project)
(1,1)
(1,1) <-- error!
(2,1)
```

Alternatively you could use the ID as the only primary key, and add a UNIQUE restraint on (developer,project):

```
(id,developer,project)
(1,1,1)
(2,1,1) <-- error
(3,2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
developer_project table
developer_id
project_id
PRIMARY KEY (developer_id, project_id)
```

or

```
developer_project table
id
developer_id
project_id
PRIMARY KEY (id)
UNIQUE KEY (developer_id, project_id)
```

---

I suggest you use the first option, unless you have reasons not to. There are ORMs out there that do not cope well with compound (primary) keys.