# Table with no unique column in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE group_edits (
  vfile_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  editor_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  edits text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There is no unique index, because one editor_id can edit multiple vfile_ids, also one vfile_id can be edited by multiple editor_ids.

phpMyAdmin 4.1.6 does not allow me to edit this table saying:

```
Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

Now it makes me thing is there anything wrong with the table like this? Rows are unique when you take a value of editor_id AND vfile_id while none of the columns alone is unique.

I know that to fix it I could add

```
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

but it does not reflect the design of my database schema and I would like to avoid adding tricks just to make phpMyAdmin work.

Is my database design wrong or is it phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I wouldn't call adding an `ID` column a "trick".  That's what I would suggest in this scenario.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Is there any reason to add `ID` column from the point of view of my application, not phpMyAdmin?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187643/do-mysql-tables-need-an-id

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, but I would never reverence this column in any query - that's why I hesitate if it would be of any use. Thanks for pointing to more reading!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolution: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922503/resolution-this-table-does-not-contain-a-unique-column-grid-edit-checkbox-ed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure you can make a unique primary compound key of (editor_id, vfile_id), go ahead and do that.

```
 ALTER TABLE group_edits ADD PRIMARY KEY (editor_id, vfile_id)
```

You'd be wise to use phpmyadmin to dump a copy of the table first, so you can restore it if you mess it up.

That should permit phpmyadmin to let you update rows in the table.

Comment: Composite primary key, never knew about it. I see my question is quite old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737190/composite-primary-key-or-not