# Should the normal Key include the primary key?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

This question is related to 
[Do MySQL tables need an ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187643/do-mysql-tables-need-an-id)

There is a meaningless auto_incremental ID acting as PRIMARY KEY for a table, then when I create other KEYs, should I include this ID in the KEYs?

For example, in this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(50),
  `states`  varchar(50),
  `city`    varchar(50),
  `county`  varchar(50),
  `zip`     int(5),
  PRIMARY KEY(ID),
  KEY zip1 (zip),
  KEY zip2 (zip, ID)
} ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Because I need to search the table using zip code a lot, so I need a KEY start from zip code. I should use either KEY zip1 or KEY zip2. Which one of these two KEYs is better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For InnoDB, [the primary key is always included in secondary indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html);

> All indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes. In InnoDB, **each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row**, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index. InnoDB uses this primary key value to search for the row in the clustered index.

In other words, `ID` is already included in `zip1`, and does not have to be mentioned as it is in in `zip2`.

Comment: Thanks. The official document is very helpful.

Comment: This is sort of true. I can add that although the clustered key (`id` in this case) is included in every secondary key *within InnoDB*, MySQL itself doesn't actually know this. There are situations where including the clustered key columns (or a subset of them) will improve the optimizer's decision making. For instance, if you have `SELECT id FROM t WHERE a=5 ORDER BY id DESC` you can avoid an extra sort by making the index on `(a, id)`. Furthermore, including the cluster key in the index definition doesn't take any extra space, since the column data is there already.